# a:hover above img doesnt work properly with display block under IE & Opera

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, image

Had anyone got a problem with **a:hover** that has **position: absolute** and is above **<img>** under IE & Opera

**a:hover** has background, but `<a>` hasn't, both has `display: block`.

`Thank you in advance for your help`

...

To see the problem please check this webpage: 
http://bckp.eu/test.html

or

use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
}
a.next {
    right: 0;
}
a.prev {
    left:0;
}
.withbackground {
    background: yellow;
}
.nobackground {
    background: transparent;
}
a.link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:0;
}
a.link:hover, a.link:focus {
    background: url(/img/comment.gif) repeat !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="t">
        <a class="link nobackground" href="#">&lt;a&gt; without background</a>
        <img src="/img/DSC_00641.jpg" height="200" width="500" alt="Dummy img" />
    </div>
    <p>Doesnt work under IE? <a href="#false" onclick="return a();">Add background</a> | This is not <a href="#" onclick="quirks()">quirks mode</a> <a href="http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/quirksmode.html">#</a></p>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <a class="link withbackground" href="#">&lt;a&gt; with background</a>
        <img src="/img/DSC_00641.jpg" height="200" width="500" alt="Dummy img" />
    </div>
    <div> <a class="link nobackground" href="#">&lt;a&gt; without background, without img</a> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function a() {
            document.body.innerHTML+='<style>#t a {background: pink;}</style>';return false;
        }
        function quirks() {
            alert(document.compatMode); return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one seriously wacky bug. Now, if you really must organize your html the way you have, then IE needs to have the following placed *inside* the `a` tag to get it to register with the image.

```
<div style="position: absolute; filter: alpha(opacity=0); background: red; top: 0px; left: 0px"></div>
```

But this would be better (have not tested completely across browsers). Organize the html like (no need for a wrapper `div`):

```
<a><img /></a>
```

Make sure the `a` is not `position: absolute` (IE7 didn't work with it so), and then set the image to:

```
img {position: absolute; z-index: -1}
```

I hope these head you in a direction to solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scott, thank you for your answer. This is just example of the problem.

Of course my real code is bigger than that: 
- 2  tags to navigate prev/next (so I cant put `<a><img></a>`)
- both 's has  but with display: none (`<a><span>prev</span></a>`). display: block doesnt help

z-index doesnt help. position: absolute works, when `<a>` has background.

I cant have filter: alpha(opacity=0) or opacity=0 because not every browser supports that.

I found odd solution that solves the problem, but dont want to use it: `a {background: url(filedoesnotexists);}` or i can use for example transparent 1x1 gif file but i would like to find reason of my problem.

Solution with `img{position: absolute; z-index: -1;} div{position: relative;} a{position: static;}` works exactly the same - no hovering without background above img for ie & opera

### I also met another odd thing with that in my main code - will try to reproduce it. (EDIT below)

This is another strange problem - IE works, but only when it has another "layer" and mouse is hovering above this layer. Opera works fine in every case:

http://bckp.eu/test2.html - click Exif info and move mouse over image/new "layer"

Comment: I also ran into this problem. I "fixed" it by adding a blank.gif background image to the empty absolute-positioned container.